# How to select or not select a row depending on the value of another row in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
+----------+------------+
| name     | code       |
+----------+------------+
| Fluffy   | 000        |
| Claws    | 217        |
| Buffy    | 598        |
| Fang     | 000        |
| Bowser   | 687        |
| Chirpy   | 587        |
| Whistler | 258        |
| Slim     | 298        |
| Fluffy   | 168        |
+----------+------------+
```

Here's my problem... in the above table the default value for column "code" is 000.In the column "name", Fluffy has 2 code one is the default 000 & the other one 168 When selecting, if fluffy has something other than the default code i've to select that & other rows leaving out the one row with default for Fluffy.Any way to do that with mysql IF or any other ? Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Will you be having more than one code other than the default one??

Answer (score 0):

Use `max()` to get the highest code. If there is only `000` then that will be returned.

```
select name, max(code) as code
from your_table
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,MAX(code) FROM myTABLE GROUP BY name
```

This will select the highest code for that person, assuming all your other codes will be positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use MAX(code) for that:

```
SELECT name, MAX(code)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
```